# how to get values of jquery select2 tags list using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to get select values of jquery select2 plugin in asp.net code behind.

Here is my source

**Client Side:**

```
 <select id="ddlcountry" runat="server"  class="select" style="width: 100%;">                                                                                                       
 </select>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
var query1 = from pcountry in CTX.Countries
              orderby pcountry.Country1 ascending
              select new
             {
              pcountry.CountryId,
              pcountry.CountryName
              };

            if (query1 != null)
            {
                ddlcountry.DataSource = query1.ToList();
                ddlcountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
                ddlcountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
                ddlcountry.DataBind();               

                ddlcountry.Multiple = true;
            }

 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  Now i want to get all the selected country values here ?

}
```

Please help me,i will be very thankful.

Comment: Wont it be in the http response? query1 looks like its floating in no mans land

Answer (score 0):

If you're not creating the `<select>` element as an `<ASP:DropDownList>` control, then I don't believe you will have access to properties and methods such as "Datasource", etc. You can, however, access HTML elements that have the `runat="server"` attribute added.

I believe the `<option>` tag is of the generic HTML control type. I stick to VB.Net, so I'll have to write some psuedo code for you...

```
For each o as HtmlGenericControl in ddlcountry.Children.ofType(of HtmlGenericControl)
    If o.Attributes("selected") then
        ' Here you can access your option value using the "value" attribute (and InnerHtml works too, I think)
    End if
Next o
```

---

Here's a link to an answer where I showed how to loop through generic controls using a working example:

- [how can I get HTML attribute from ASP/VB.net code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934788/how-can-i-get-html-attribute-from-asp-vb-net-codebehind/28935885#28935885)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lopsided,i appreciate your kind help.I tried this but it doesn't work for me.

According to your answer i thought some solution,should i get the select2 option list value in client side and store it into hiddenfield and then i get the hidden field value into server side code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the items collection to find out which countries have been selected.

```
foreach (ListItem li in ddlcountry.Items) {
    if ((li.Selected)) {
        //Selected Country
    }
}
```